# Wordpress activate_plugin() can run and return "The plugin does not have a valid header."

Tags: wordpress

hello i tried to build plugin that can install and activate other plugins. the plugins is successfully extracted to "wp-content/plugins" folder but there error when activate_plugin() function running, it return "The plugin does not have a valid header.". Did i do it wrong?

this my plugin script:

```
<?php

define( 'WP_ADMIN', TRUE );
define( 'WP_NETWORK_ADMIN', TRUE );
define( 'WP_USER_ADMIN', TRUE );

require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/admin.php');
require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php');

try {
  $post = $_POST;
  // file_put_contents('logs.txt', json_encode($post));die;
  foreach($post['plugins'] as $key => $value){
    if($value['is_external_link'] == 0){
      $file_url = $post['url_download']."/{$value['id']}";
    }else{
      $file_url = $value['external_link'];
    }
    $tmp_file = download_url($file_url);
    copy($tmp_file, $value['file_name']);
    unlink($tmpfile);
    // extract plugin to plugins folder
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open($value['file_name']);
    $zip->extractTo(ABSPATH.'wp-content/plugins/');
    $zip->close();
    // remove zip file
    unlink($value['file_name']);
    // activate plugin
    $res = activate_plugin(ABSPATH.'wp-content/plugins/'.$value['folder_name']);
    file_put_contents("logs$key.txt", $res->get_error_messages());
  }
} catch (\Throwable $th) {
  file_put_contents('log.txt', $th);
}
```

Comment: so your plugin script is used to install any other plugins, and is accessible for anyone to use in side the plugins folder?

Answer (score 0):

Oviously, your code missing plugin header right after the open <?php tag.
It's some thing like this:

```
/**
 * Plugin Name:       My Basics Plugin
 * Plugin URI:        https://example.com/plugins/the-basics/
 * Description:       Handle the basics with this plugin.
 * Version:           1.10.3
 * Requires at least: 5.2
 * Requires PHP:      7.2
 * Author:            John Smith
 * Author URI:        https://author.example.com/
 * License:           GPL v2 or later
 * License URI:       https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 * Text Domain:       my-basics-plugin
 * Domain Path:       /languages
 */
```

Or atleat you need the Plugin Name to activate it!!

Comment: the header was there, and i already got the solution for my problem and i'll put it in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Oh the problem already clear, i just need to include the core file script, so instead of "wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/", change to "wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/plugin-name.php".